# i cannot understand MATLAB syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax

In MATLAB, i was faced with a incomprehensible syntax.

```
for i = [1:n-1,n+1:N]
    Z{i} = U{i}(:,r);
end
```

if you knows exactly, please let me know. 
(if you show some example(e.g. when n=1, N=3), i can understand your explain easily.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax basically means:

```
for i = [1:n-1,n+1:N]
```

This just means that i will sequentially take the values defined in the array:
`1` till `n-1` increasing by `1` and after it will continue from `n+1` till `N`. It will skip `n` in other words.

```
Z{i} = U{i}(:,r);
```

`{` represent cells so the ith cell of `Z` (imagine `Z` and `U` as cell arrays) will be assigned the content of ith cell of `U` from which it will keep though only the r-th column (I guess its a matrix of some kind).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. it is very helpful to me. my English skill is very poor, but you understood my questions. thank you very much.

Comment: @Idontknow.T.T Don't forget to "accept" the question (click on the tick mark) if it completely satisfied your needs.